# Connecting external display to Early 2015 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, displayport, 4k

Does Early 2015 MacBook Pro output 4K 3840 via Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort? I seem to get only HD max option on YouTube videos.

I have a Samsung U32J590U 31.5" 4K UHD monitor. If not, do I have to get a real Thunderbolt cable or is HDMI-to-HDMI the answer?

Answer (score 0):

### Display Support:

Supports an HDMI-compatible device, including 4K, while using one Thunderbolt display or support for two Thunderbolt displays

### External Resolution:

**HDMI**

- 3840 by 2160 pixels at 30Hz
- 4096 by 2160 pixels at 24Hz

**Thunderbolt**

- 3840 by 2160 pixels at 60Hz
- 5120 by 2880 pixels at 60Hz (with Radeon R9 M370X)